# What needs updating when moving site from subdomain to root?

Tags: subdomain

I've just moved a site from a subdomain to the root.

So far I've updated the index.php file and also the settings in the control panel

System->General->SiteUrl

to reflect the new path of the craft directory and index.php relationship.

I can access the admin backend but the actual site gives the craft styled "Page not found."

Answer (score 2):

Ok so on this site:

1) I forgot that I'd moved the templates folder outside the craft folder for easy access with this in the index.php

```
define('CRAFT_PLUGINS_PATH',realpath(dirname(__FILE__)./../plugins").'/');
```

2) Making sure the assets sources url are changed is essential to get the site working.